# Android Listview & CustomAdapter getView Issues

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

Currently working to develop a custom adapater, to display data on a list row as follows:

---

### |TextView| |TextView| |TextView| |TextView|

Currently I am using this tutorial for reference.

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

However, as mentioned, I encounter a problem with the customeradapter, specifically when creating an inflator and in also identifying the ID for Textview in the custom row xml.

Here are the two lines that throw up errors:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
```

&

```
holder.food = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.foodName);
```

Errors given are: LayoutInflater cannot be resolved to a type & R cannot be resolved to a variable.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Imports

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
```

My full implementation for the adapter:

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReportSummary>{

    private Context             context; 
    private int                 layoutResourceId;    
    private List<ReportSummary> report = new ArrayList<ReportSummary>();

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<ReportSummary> report) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, report);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.report = report;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View        row     = convertView;
        ViewHolder  holder  = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.food = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.foodName);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.food.setText(report.get(0).getFoodName());
        holder.status.setText(report.get(0).getStatus());
        //holder.foodRDA.setText(report.get(0).getStatus());
        holder.userLvl.setText(report.get(0).getLevel());

        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder  {
        TextView food;
        TextView status;
        TextView userLvl;
        TextView foodRDA;
        TextView difference;
    }
}
```

XML layouts

activity_diet_analysis

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DietAnalysisActivity" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

row_diet_analysis

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


 <TextView android:id="@+id/foodName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:text="TTTT"
    />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/foodName"
    android:text="TJJDFDFDF"
    />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/foodRDA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/status"
    android:text="TTTT"
    />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/userLvl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/foodRDA"
    android:text="TTTT"
    />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/difference"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userLvl"
    android:text="TTTT"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Rashmi, Ive updated the original with the error descriptions.

Comment: @MindDrip fix any errors in resource files. and show your imports

Comment: there are no errors in the resource files. Imports updated in original post.

Comment: @MindDrip there must be errors in resource files. Hence R.java is not generated

Comment: thats what i thought too but really, no errors. I have updated the original with my xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the errors you mentioned, you probably need to import LayoutInflator:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
```

And import the generated R file for your app:

```
import com.example.app.R
```

Be sure you import the correct R file too, not `android.R`.

Also, if you're using an IDE such as Eclipse or Android Studio (which you probably should be), it will do this for you automatically.

Note that the R file will not be generated for your project if you have any errors in your resources files.